# Exercise of Invertible matrix and other commutable

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the appropriate substitution to demonstrate the commutability and existence of the inverse

Let the matrix $A$ $3\times 2 $. Show that the following matrices are conmutable

a) $\left ( A\left ( A^{T}A \right )^{-1}A^{T} \right )^{3}-\left ( A\left ( A^{T}A \right )^{-1}A^{T} \right )+I-B$;

$\left [ \left ( A\left ( A^{T}A \right )^{-1}A^{T} \right )^{3}-\left ( A\left ( A^{T}A \right )^{-1}A^{T} \right )+I-B \right ]^{-1}$

b) Show that if $A^{3}=0$,
 then $A+I$ is invertible matrix,

where $0$ null matrix and $I$ identity matrix

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

(a) Follows from the definition of the inverse of a matrix. Say your expression is matrix C, then as long as $C$ is invertible, it commutes with its inverse.

(b) $(A+I)^{-1}=A^2-A+I$. This follows from $I=I-A^3=(I+A)(I-A+A^2)$. You can verify it is both right and left inverse.